# Edit SearchSourceBuilder in Elasticsearch Java API

Tags: elasticsearch

I am given an existing SearchSourceBuilder that needs to have a boolean clauses added to it.

How do I add the clause without changing the existing query using the Elasticsearch API?

```
public void example(SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder) {
   SearchQuery originalQuery = searchSourceBuilder.query();

   //Edit the originalQuery to include a boolean must_not 

   SearchSourceBuilder.query(originalQuery);
}
```

Comment: You need to provide some code so we can better understand what you're dealing with.

Comment: Added an example